# How to generate string from variable in a function and show it by serial port (ESP8266)

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I use to program different microcontrollers, but at low level. I mean, I program them to control power converters and so.

However, I am interested in working with the nodemcu (ESP8266) due to the fact that messages can be send via MQTT protocol.

I did a very easy program generating the messages by concatenating strings. Now I am trying to do the same thing but in a more elegant way i.e. with functions. Due to my poor skills, I sweating like a pig trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Hope you can help me! :D

Here is the code. As you can see, I have a float variable that increases with a counter, just to change its value, you know. Then, I call a function to generate the message and send it to the serial port (later it would be MQTT).

```
#include <string.h>               // Libreria para trabajar con caracteres

int contador=1;
float Vbat=2.1;                   // tension de la bateria
char *Vbat_en_string;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

// This function generates the message. Turns float into string.
void generamensaje(float valor, char* destino) 
{
  //I need to do this. Otherwise, dtostrf doesn't work
  destino ="";
  //Saving float "valor" in string "destino"
  dtostrf(valor,6,3,destino);
}

void loop() {
  
  generamensaje(Vbat,Vbat_en_string);
  Serial.print("Message:");
  Serial.println(Vbat_en_string);
  contador++;
  Vbat = Vbat + contador*1.0024;

  delay(2000);
}
```

This should generate something like:

```
Message: 3926.496

Message: 4015.709

Message: 4105.925
```

But what I read in the serial port is:

```
Message:
3926.496Message:

4015.709Message:

4105.925
```

Could you help me a little? I thought Serial.println automatically changed the line.

Thank you so much, community.

Once we have this solved, I have more questions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
  //I need to do this. Otherwise, dtostrf doesn't work
  destino ="";
```

Is quite definitely incorrect, since it makes `destino` point to a zero length string *constant*, then `dtostrf` then writes to that location, which is both *constant* and *too short*.  The consequent behaviour is undefined.  You do need to change the code to make it work, but that is not the correct solution.

Instead `Vbat_en_string` should point to a buffer of sufficient length *before* `generamensaje()` is called.  It also need not be global - you should avoid globals where possible and it is *possible* in all cases - unfortunately most Arduino sketch examples are poor in this respect and as a "teaching" platform set a bad example:

```
include <string.h>               // Libreria para trabajar con caracteres

void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// This function generates the message. Turns float into string.
void generamensaje(float valor, char* destino) 
{
  //Saving float "valor" in string "destino"
  dtostrf(valor,6,3,destino);
}

void loop() 
{
  static int contador=1;
  static float Vbat=2.1;      // tension de la bateria

  char Vbat_en_string[32] ;
  generamensaje(Vbat,Vbat_en_string);

  Serial.print("Message:");
  Serial.println(Vbat_en_string);

  contador++;
  Vbat = Vbat + contador*1.0024;

  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: I will try what you say.
Thanks Clifford :)

Comment: Dear Clifford,
Thanks for showing me I have no idea... Your code  works perfectly. Hope you are around when I prepare my next post in stack overflow.
Greetings and have a nice day.

Comment: Note that the only change necessary to make _your_ code work is to remove the assignment of `Vbat_en_string` in `generamensaje` and change its type from a pointer to an array.  The elimination of globals is just _advice_, and because I could not bring myself to post code with unnecessary globals, as a matter of professional integrity ;-)  Worth a read: https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/